# Find the depth of children and their children emanating from a parent element in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, algorithm

I have a data frame with `parent_id` and `child_id` columns. A snippet of the data frame is below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'child_id': [11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 32, 33, 34, 35, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44, 56, 57, 58, 59, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 78, 79, 80, 81],
                   'parent_id': [10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 17, 32, 33, 17, 33, 41, 42, 43, 42, 44, 56, 57, 57, 59, 63, 64, 65, 65, 67, 78, 79, 79],
                  })

   child_id  parent_id
0        11         10
1        12         11
2        17         16
3        18         17
4        19         18
...
```

I want to get an array that shows for each `parent_id`, how many steps below the children (rollout) went.

For example, for `parent_id` 10, there will be two elements in the returned array. The first element will have a value of 2 as it has `child_id` 11, and then 11 has 12. 10 also starts another rollout with `child_id` 20 that goes 3 steps deep. Hence, for 10 the returned array shall have 2 elements `[2, 3]`

The next rollout at 13 is the corner case. It produces a rollout with 4 children, one of whom (`child_id`: 33) produces further 4 children, one of these produces (`child_id`: 42) further 3. One of these (`child_id`: 57) starts two further rollouts. One rollout has 1 child and the other has further 6 children. So for `child_id` 13, I should get a rollout depth of `[12, 17]`.

The total returned array should `[2, 3, 12, 17]`. I am struggling to get the corner case included in the solution.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: "*10 also starts another rollout with child_id 20 that goes 3 steps deep*" -> are you sure? seems like it doesn't fit the provided data

Comment: I cant find `13` anywhere in the data, so what does this _"The next rollout at 13 ..."_ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a graph problem.

Here is how your graph looks like:

[image]

If I understand correctly, you want to know the length of all possible paths from a given node to the end.

For instance, taking a subset of the graph. There are 3 possible paths from 65, of lengths 1 (to 66), 4 (to 80), and 4 (to 81).

[image]

You can use `networkx` to compute the graph, then determine the terminal nodes as those that do not have children using `set` operations. Starting fro each terminal node, go back recursively and count the edges to each given node saving the distance in a dictionary (`defaultdict`):

```
# set up graph
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent_id', target='child_id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# compute paths
from collections import defaultdict
successors = defaultdict(list)
def get_parent(n, num=0):
    for p in G.predecessors(n):
        successors[p].append(num+1)
        get_parent(p, num+1)

parents = set(df['parent_id'])
children = set(df['child_id'])
terminal = children-parents

for t in terminal:
    get_parent(t)

print(dict(successors))
```

output:

```
{33: [1, 11, 10, 14, 13, 14, 13, 7, 6],
 32: [2, 12, 11, 15, 14, 15, 14, 8, 7],
 17: [3, 1, 13, 12, 16, 15, 16, 15, 5, 9, 8],
 16: [4, 2, 14, 13, 17, 16, 17, 16, 6, 10, 9],
 65: [1, 4, 4],
 64: [2, 5, 5],
 63: [3, 6, 6],
 59: [4, 7, 7],
 57: [5, 8, 8, 1],
 56: [6, 9, 9, 2],
 44: [7, 10, 10, 3],
 43: [8, 11, 11, 4],
 42: [9, 8, 12, 11, 12, 11, 5, 4],
 41: [10, 9, 13, 12, 13, 12, 6, 5],
 11: [1],
 10: [2],
 79: [1, 1],
 78: [2, 2],
 67: [3, 3],
 21: [1],
 20: [2],
 19: [3],
 18: [4]}
```

Finally, to merge to your original dataframe:

```
df.merge(pd.Series(successors, name='paths'),
         left_on='parent_id', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
    child_id  parent_id                                     paths
0         11         10                                       [2]
1         12         11                                       [1]
2         17         16  [4, 2, 14, 13, 17, 16, 17, 16, 6, 10, 9]
3         18         17   [3, 1, 13, 12, 16, 15, 16, 15, 5, 9, 8]
8         32         17   [3, 1, 13, 12, 16, 15, 16, 15, 5, 9, 8]
11        35         17   [3, 1, 13, 12, 16, 15, 16, 15, 5, 9, 8]
4         19         18                                       [4]
5         20         19                                       [3]
6         21         20                                       [2]
7         22         21                                       [1]
9         33         32         [2, 12, 11, 15, 14, 15, 14, 8, 7]
10        34         33         [1, 11, 10, 14, 13, 14, 13, 7, 6]
12        41         33         [1, 11, 10, 14, 13, 14, 13, 7, 6]
13        42         41             [10, 9, 13, 12, 13, 12, 6, 5]
14        43         42              [9, 8, 12, 11, 12, 11, 5, 4]
16        44         42              [9, 8, 12, 11, 12, 11, 5, 4]
15        44         43                            [8, 11, 11, 4]
17        56         44                            [7, 10, 10, 3]
18        57         56                              [6, 9, 9, 2]
19        58         57                              [5, 8, 8, 1]
20        59         57                              [5, 8, 8, 1]
21        63         59                                 [4, 7, 7]
22        64         63                                 [3, 6, 6]
23        65         64                                 [2, 5, 5]
24        66         65                                 [1, 4, 4]
25        67         65                                 [1, 4, 4]
26        78         67                                    [3, 3]
27        79         78                                    [2, 2]
28        80         79                                    [1, 1]
29        81         79                                    [1, 1]
```

###### result for your [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799019/find-the-average-depth-of-the-number-of-children-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1)

graph:

[image]

output:

```
    child_id  parent_id   paths
0         11         10  [2, 3]
5         20         10  [2, 3]
1         12         11     [1]
2         17         16     [3]
3         18         17     [2]
4         19         18     [1]
6         21         20     [2]
7         22         21     [1]
8         32         13  [4, 8]
9         33         32  [3, 7]
10        34         33  [2, 6]
12        41         33  [2, 6]
11        35         34     [1]
13        42         41     [5]
14        43         42     [4]
15        44         43     [3]
16        56         44     [2]
17        57         56     [1]
```

Comment: Hey Mozway, Thank you! that really solves my problem, minor improvements I have to do are to only keep the results for `parent_id` that are unique. For example, 11 is the child of 10. So I am not interested in how many steps deep it went down from 11. I think Ill do that once the data frame has been formed. I can see which values in parent_id are unique. Keep the paths for those and remove the rest. Shouldn't be difficult. Then I can calculate the states like average depth, deepness etc.

Lastly, I am using `nx.draw(G, pos=nx.planar_layout(G)). How can I get a graph like you produced. Thx

Comment: @ViperMaverick then you can modify the recursive `get_parent` to only add to the dictionary of it reached a root (i.e. of the predecessor node doesn't have predecessors itself). For the graph, browse my `networkx` answers, I think I have posted it.