# Find the average depth of the number of children in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, algorithm, tree

I have a data frame (df) with a parent_id and child_id columns. A small portion of the df is shown below to explain the problem.

| child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 10 |
| 12 | 11 |
| 17 | 16 |
| 18 | 17 |
| 19 | 18 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 21 | 20 |
| 22 | 21 |
| 32 | 13 |
| 33 | 32 |
| 34 | 33 |
| 35 | 34 |
| 41 | 33 |
| 42 | 41 |
| 43 | 42 |
| 44 | 43 |
| 56 | 44 |
| 57 | 56 |

I want to get an array that shows for each original (parentless) `parent_id` (e.g. 10, 16, 13), how many **steps** below (rollout) the children and the grandchildren went.

For example, for `parent_id:10`, there will be two elements in the returned array. The first element will have a value of 2 as it went two steps deep. It has `child_id:11`, and then `11` has `12`.

`parent_id:10` also starts another rollout with `child_id:20` that goes 3 steps deep. Hence, for 10 the returned array shall have 2 elements `[2, 3]`.

Similarlry, for `parent_id 16`, 3 steps deep. For `parent_id:13`, 10 steps deep. Thus the returned array would be `[2, 3, 3, 10]`.

Comment: I just [answered your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792001/find-the-depth-of-children-and-their-children-emanating-from-a-parent-element-in/71799105#71799105) is this the same?

Comment: Maybe you can update the other question with the data of this one as it is more minimal, I provided the answer for both there.

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway. I just saw both of your answers on the previous thread. I am going through them now. I will then appropriately upvote and close both these threads. Thanks a lot once again.